# Passing base64 string using c# string variable. Error: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, string, base64

Still A Newbie.
I would like to replace the long Base64 string with a variable but keep getting error: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Scenario: I am retrieving the full base64 string from SQL database e.g data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7

I then split the string for the section that I want that is after the ','.

```
    public SqlDataReader reader;
    public String ClientSigImg;
    public String ClientSigImg1;

    ClientSigImg = reader[0].ToString();
    ClientSigImg1 = ClientSigImg.Split(',')[1];
```

So the above base64 string changes on user input and instead of manual input like below

```
    string base64 = @"R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
```

I would like to replace that long string with:

```
    string base64 = @""+ ClientSigImg1 +"";
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
```

Comment: Please DEBUG your code step by step to see why the string was not an array of 2.

Comment: You realise that `string base64 = @""+ ClientSigImg1 +"";` doesn't actually do anything that `string base64 = ClientSigImg1;` doesn't do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though:

```
ClientSigImg = reader[0].ToString();
```

Is **NOT** returning a string with a comma in it (please debug and confirm). This means that you will see the error you are describing when this line of code runs:

```
ClientSigImg1 = ClientSigImg.Split(',')[1];
```

This is because index 1 will not exist. So, check that you are actually getting the correct data returned from your query.

In addition, once your query does return the correct data you can tidy your code and simply use:

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ClientSigImg1);
```

That is because:

```
string base64 = @""+ ClientSigImg1 +"";
```

Doesn't actually do anything other than add empty string before and after your string, hence, doesn't add anything!

Comment: i have confirmed and tried all day yesterday and still nothin . i debugged and i can confirm that it is returning a string.

Comment: What I meant was a string CONTAINING a comma. When you debug do you see a comma in the string? Might be worth putting split on separate line so `var splitDebug = ClientSigImg.Split(',');` and then step over that to see what `splitDebug` contains (I am guessing length=1 so no index 1).